# php destroy session and delete record from mysql on closing browser / tab

Tags: php, mysql, session

i have Question Answers quizes php forms... when user answers the questions at the end he/she will get the result.

i want that if in a quiz there are 5 questions and user close the browser or tab after submitting 1 question. i want that if user close the browser or tab or if that page is opened in lightbox iframe, upon closing his submitted data will be deleted from the database based on session id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `onbefore` event that the window trigger just before it were closed. You can get more details on:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

If you're using jQuery you just need to listen to that event, and then send your session ID to a php script that receive the Session ID and delete your records.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function (e) {
    // code to execute when browser is closed
    $.post("delete_with_sessionID.php", { action: 'delete', sid: '<?php echo $_SESSION['ID']; ?>' });      
});
```

Comment: nothing happened... i have opened the page in lightbox as outside page in iframe. even when i open it in a different tab it does not work.

Comment: That called php page has to have the code to clean up what you want - session, some mysql data etc...

Comment: yes @TomasH would you please help me??? i did this for when users completes the form then i ran a query to wash the data from mysql table it works fine but i dont know how to do that if a user doesnt complete the quiz and quits before then how to clean the data from mysql table

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand your question - if you say you already have the code written when the user completes the action, removing sessions using [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) or executing *some* SQL against the database is along the same principles?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by set an expiration time for your quiz like 5 or 10 minutes. when user start quiz, save the current time in database then you can check your database and remove expired and uncompleted quizzes.

You can remove records with simple php and mysql code or use [MySQL Scheduled Event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html) automation.

SQL Code:

```
DELETE FROM quiz WHERE time_started < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) and quiz_completed != 1
```

MySQL Scheduled Event:

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 MINUTE
DO
  DELETE FROM quiz WHERE time_started < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) and quiz_completed != 1
```

to use MySQL Scheduled Event you have to execute the following command

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Comment: well if this command will execute and the one who is completing the quiz, his/her data will be deleted also ????

Comment: it's just a sample code, you can change it to remove only uncompleted quizzes.

Comment: you have to tell to user they have only 10 minutes to complete the quiz. you can change expiration time to 30 minutes, or even change expiration time base on last user request.